# How to stroke text when drawing it with DrawString function in GDI+?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi+, gdi

There's a GDI's [StrokePath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145124(v=vs.85).aspx) API that can allow to simulate "stroking" of text using [this method](http://ntcoder.com/bab/2008/03/21/drawing-outlined-text/). I'll copy it here:

```
void CCanvas::DrawOutlineText( CDC& dc, const CString& Text )
{
  const int RestorePoint = dc.SaveDC();

  // Create new font
  CFont NewFont;
  NewFont.CreatePointFont( 700, TEXT( "Verdana" ), &dc );

  // Use this font
  dc.SelectObject( &NewFont );

  // Brush for pen
  LOGBRUSH lBrushForPen = { 0 };
  lBrushForPen.lbColor = RGB( 200, 150, 100 );
  lBrushForPen.lbHatch = HS_CROSS;
  lBrushForPen.lbStyle = BS_SOLID;

  // New pen for drawing outline text
  CPen OutlinePen;
  OutlinePen.CreatePen( PS_GEOMETRIC | PS_SOLID, 2, &lBrushForPen, 0, 0 );

  // Use this pen
  dc.SelectObject( &OutlinePen );

  dc.SetBkMode( TRANSPARENT );

  dc.BeginPath();
  // This text is not drawn on screen, but instead each action is being
  // recorded and stored internally as a path, since we called BeginPath
  dc.TextOut( 20, 20, Text );
  // Stop path
  dc.EndPath();

  // Now draw outline text
  dc.StrokePath();

  dc.RestoreDC( RestorePoint );
}
```

In my case I'm using [DrawString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms535991(v=vs.85).aspx) function from GDI+ to draw text.

Does anyone know if there's an alternative to `BeginPath`, `EndPath` and `StrokePath` in GDI+ to simulate text stroking?

**EDIT:** *Following the advice by `jschroedl` below, I tried the following:*

```
CString str = L"Text";

Graphics grpx(dc.GetSafeHdc());

SolidBrush gdiBrush(Color(0xFF, 0xFF, 0, 0));

StringFormat gdiSF;
gdiSF.SetAlignment(StringAlignmentNear);
gdiSF.SetFormatFlags(StringFormatFlagsNoWrap | StringFormatFlagsNoFitBlackBox | 
    StringFormatFlagsNoFontFallback | StringFormatFlagsNoClip);
gdiSF.SetHotkeyPrefix(HotkeyPrefixNone);
gdiSF.SetTrimming(StringTrimmingNone);

grpx.SetTextRenderingHint(TextRenderingHintAntiAlias);
grpx.SetPixelOffsetMode(PixelOffsetModeNone);
grpx.SetInterpolationMode(InterpolationModeHighQualityBicubic);

GraphicsPath dd;
FontFamily gdiFF(L"Segoe UI");
const PointF pntF(0, 0);
dd.AddString(str, str.GetLength(), &gdiFF, FontStyleRegular, 58.0f, pntF, &gdiSF);

Pen penFF(Color(0xFF, 0xFF, 0, 0), 1.0f);
grpx.DrawPath(&penFF, &dd);
```

*that produced quite a jagged outline (enlarged screenshot):*

[image]

Any idea how to make it render with anti-aliasing?

Answer (score 0):

I believe our code creates a `GraphicsPath` object, calls `GraphicsPath::AddString()` to get the path for the text and later draws the path with `Graphics::DrawPath()`.

Update:

Based on the blocky text, I experimented and think this looks a bit smoother.

```
grpx.SetTextRenderingHint(TextRenderingHintClearTypeGridFit);
grpx.SetSmoothingMode(SmoothingModeHighQuality);
grpx.SetPixelOffsetMode(PixelOffsetModeHalf);
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. Thanks. Just curious if there's a way to add anti-aliasing to the pen being drawn. It looks pretty chunky.

Comment: Looking at our code, we seem to set that on the Graphics object using SetInterpolationMode(InterpolationModeHighQualityBicubic) and there's a comment about addressing 'blocky text' :-) just before we call graphics->SetTextRenderingHint(TextRenderingHintAntiAlias) then SetPixelOffsetMode(PixelOffsetModeNone)

Comment: You know it didn't change anything. See my updated original post w/code.

Comment: Updated my answer - I think it's closer to what you're after.